# Action button in the notification bar is not coming

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using this code for custom notification .Problem is that the whole text that is in string is coming in single line .secondly no action button is visible.

```
     private void showNotification(String msg){
    //Creating a notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert);
    builder.setContentTitle("Alert");
    builder.setContentText(msg);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    //builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_call, "Accept", pendingIntent).build();
   //  builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_alert, "Reject", pendingIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [BigTextStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle.html) for notifications with more than one line of text and [NotificationCompat.Action](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Action.html) for action button.

```
private void showNotification(String msg) {
//Creating a notification
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert);
builder.setContentTitle("Alert");
builder.setContentText(msg);
builder.setAutoCancel(false);
builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_call, "Accept", pendingIntent);
// builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_alert, "Reject", pendingIntent);
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg));
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: I have added these lines in the code but still the same problem      .........                      Notification.Builder buil =new Notification.Builder(this);........
        buil.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(msg)); .........                                                                                                              new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_call, "CALL", pendingIntent);

Comment: did you call [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#addAction(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action)) method on your `NotificationCompat.Builder`?

Comment: setStyle is called by Notification class                                                                              Notification.Builder buil =new Notification.Builder(this);

Comment: Also tried this                                                                                                                      NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        //Notification.Builder buil =new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(msg));

Comment: From your post `builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_call, "Accept", pendingIntent).build();` remove `.build()` from that line and on the next line write `builder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle() .bigText(msg));`

Comment: still same problem

Comment: but the size of notification bar is increased

Comment: Try different icon for your action.

Comment: What's API version?